# Angular PDF viewer: How to use

Tags: angularjs, pdf, viewer, pdf-viewer, angularjs-view

I need to use a pdf viewer on my web app which is in anugularjs. I found Angular PDF viewer and it's ok for me. But I don't know what code insert to use it.

At the moment I've:

in html:

```
<div ui-content-for="title">
    <span class="small"></span>
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div class="list-group">
        <site-frame style="display:block; height: 100%;">
            <pdf-viewer
                delegate-handle="my-pdf-container"
                url="pdfUrl"
                scale="1"
                show-toolbar="true"
                headers="{ 'x-you-know-whats-awesome': 'EVERYTHING' }">
                </pdf-viewer>
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loadNewFile('position/file.pdf')">Load</button>
    </site-frame>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the controller:

```
    'use strict';

    var pdfControllerModule = angular.module('pdfControllerModule', ['ServiceOModule']);

pdfControllerModule.controller('pdfController',
    ['$scope','pdfDelegate', '$routeParams', 'Service_o', function($scope, pdfDelegate ,$routeParams, Service_o) {

        $scope.pdfUrl = 'position/file.pdf';

        $scope.loadNewFile = function(url) {
            pdfDelegate
             .$getByHandle('my-pdf-container')
             .load(url);
        };


    }]);
```

what is incorrect and what code I insert?
Or If you know the correct code to insert in these two file, do you write me? Thanks Help me

Comment: What is the specific error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem with the code. Just Make sure you have reference to the pdf.js in your main application module. 
angular.module('app',['pdf'])
Also the html needs reference to the the pdf.combined and angular-pdf-viewer js files.